# XslCompiledTransform in ASP CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying implement **XslCompiledTransform** in asp core, after reading in many forums and documentation, think **XslCompiledTransform** is not supported for now, has someone been able to implement **XslCompiledTransform** in asp core? Or do you knows of another (maybe nuget) package that can do the same thing?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone has, since XSLT was abandoned (and v2 was never finished) in favor of Razor.

Our company had an implementation of XSLT to be able to generate very dynamic pages. But development was just too cumbersome so we decided to move to Razor instead. To this day im happy about this decision.

If you'd really want to create a working version i'd recommend trying to de-compile the dlls, and put it inside a aspnet core project. And try to make it build (removing all the errors).

! Be sure to check the licensing and contact Microsoft before thinking about using it or ever publishing it!

### Alternative solution

would be to write a compiler yourself.

Depending on the scope of features you use in XSLT making a compiler converting the XSLT into a C# class wouldn't be too hard.

You could use the default xml serializer and convert xslt statements to c# statements.

This would require you to dive into the [IViewEngine implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewEngines/IViewEngine.cs) and build your own version of it for easy use.

Although again i would discourage spending time on this. As it is a lot of work and it is not worth it (In my opinion) for such an old template language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we use XslCompiledTransform in our ASP.NET Core 2.0 solution targeting .NET Core.

With ASP.NET Core 1 you can target against the full .Net Framework which contains the XslCompiledTransform class.

Since august 2017 XslCompiledTransform is also supported with .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.0.
See [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=netcore-2.0#Applies_to) for all supported .NET versions.